# How to give a better looking output result?

Tags: output-formatting, output

I have got the following output and I would like to get rid of all those high values and obtain a better looking result. FulLSimplify doesn't work for this task. Do you know how to get a better looking output without all those 10^48 etc?

```
 (6.60881*10^48 beta)/(
 6.97402*10^50 Z0^2 + beta^2 (1.70645*10^47 - 8.3024*10^46 Z0^2))
```

For instance, I would like Z0 to appear only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple workaround:

```
exp=(6.60881*10^48 beta)/(6.97402*10^50 Z0^2 + beta^2 (1.70645*10^47 - 8.3024*10^46 Z0^2));

(Numerator[exp]/exp[[1]])/Collect[Simplify[Denominator[exp]/exp[[1]]], Z0]
(* (1. beta)/(0.0258208 beta^2 + (105.526 - 0.0125626 beta^2) Z0^2) *)
```

Comment: what about removing all those huge numbers and letting mathematica simplify them?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this:

```
In[347]:= ReduceAndCollect[eqn_, var_] :=
 Module[{redeqn},
  redeqn = 1/Together[Simplify[1/eqn]];
  Collect[Numerator[redeqn], var]/Collect[Denominator[redeqn], var]
 ]

In[349]:= eqn = (6.60881*10^48 beta)/(6.97402*10^50 Z0^2 + beta^2 (1.70645*10^47 - 8.3024*10^46 Z0^2));

In[350]:= ReduceAndCollect[eqn, Z0]
Out[350]= -((79.6012 beta)/(-2.05537 beta^2 + (-8400. + 1. beta^2) Z0^2))
```