# When can Mathematica simplify fractions with large constants?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I cannot get Mathematica (version 11.3.0.0 on Mac OS) to simplify this:

```
c = (2.71*^10*a)/(1.23*^14*a + 3.14*^12*b)
```

$$\frac{2.71\times 10^{10} a}{1.23\times 10^{14} a+3.14\times 10^{12} b}$$

```
Simplify[c]
```

$$\frac{2.71\times 10^{10} a}{1.23\times 10^{14} a+3.14\times 10^{12} b}$$

```
Simplify[N[c]]
```

$$\frac{2.71\times 10^{10} a}{1.23\times 10^{14} a+3.14\times 10^{12} b}$$

I just want it to divide the top and bottom by $10^{10}$.

Is this a bug?

I ask because this does simplify:

```
c = ( 1.23*^14*a^2)/(3.14*^10*a + 2.71*^8*b)
```

$$\frac{1.23\times 10^{14} a^2}{3.14\times 10^{10} a+2.71\times 10^8 b}$$

```
Simplify[c]
```

$$\frac{3917.2 a^2}{1. a+0.00863057 b}$$

I can't figure out in which cases it simplifies, and in which it doesn't.

Comment: Are either of these acceptable? `Expand[Numerator[c]/10^10]/Expand[Denominator[c]/10^10]` or `Simplify[Numerator[c]/10^10]/Simplify[Denominator[c]/10^10]`

Comment: related/possible duplicate: [How to give a better looking output result?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143845/34893).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`factorReal` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139759/why-does-the-following-expression-not-simplify/139829#139829), thought it divides by powers of `2` instead of `10` to avoid rounding errors:

```
factorReal = Plus[x_, y__] :> 
   With[{coeffs = Replace[{x, y}, Times[k_Real, __] :> k, 1]}, 
    With[{p = Round[Log2@GeometricMean@Abs@coeffs, 2]}, 
      2.^p*Distribute[2.^-p*Plus[x, y]]] /; MatchQ[coeffs, {__Real}]];

(2.71*^10*a)/(1.23*^14*a + 3.14*^12*b) /. factorReal
(*  (0.00154046 a)/(6.99174 a + 0.178488 b)  *)
```

You could change `Log2` to `Log10` and `2.^...` to `10.^...` if desired.